# insert and select record in parent child table

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I have two table CUSTOMER as parent and PROFILE as child with one to many relationship.I want to insert and select data from both table simultaneously  how?

Comment: What API are you using? JDBC? JPA 2? Something else? What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since u are using jdbc , to select parent and child write a join in mysql ,for example like below:

Select cust.id,cust.name,prof.id,prof.name from
Customer cust join profiler prof on cust.profid=prof.id

Comment: but how to insert the record in both table simultaneously

Comment: You have to insert separately.

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT statement inserts into a single table. To insert rows into two tables, you'll need to use two separate INSERT statements. Place them inside a transaction to ensure that either both are completed, or neither is completed.

You may find this useful: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html